# Vlans running slow

Tags: vlan

I have a 150 node network that was broken up in to 4 VLANS. 1 for servers, 1 for each wing of the building and one for phones. 
when I copy a large file from the server to a workstation in the server vlan it is fast. if I copy that same file from the server to a workstation in one of the other vlans it is 10 times slower. Any idea why.

Comment: What is routing between the vLans? Side note: you've got a strange vLan setup.

Answer (score 4):

Something's doing your routing, it's that you need to look at, it's either underpowered or your segments are too busy. Given you've told us *very* little that's all I can say without some actual details.